# Android two way data binding and Live data is not working

Tags: android-databinding, android-livedata

I am trying to use two way data-binding and Live Data so that changes in checkbox is observered and save button can be enabled or disabled. My Setting class looks like

```
class StaffSettings {
    private long settingId;
    private boolean showPublicly;
    private boolean acceptAppointment;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

My switch button looks as shown below

```
  <Switch
                android:id="@+id/switchShowPublicly"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:checked="@={settings.showPublicly}"
                android:theme="@style/switch_button"
                android:visibility="@{isEditable ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />
```

In my fragment I have set the values as shown below.

```
       MutableLiveData<StaffSettings> staffSettingsLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        staffSettingsLiveData.setValue(staffSettings);
        staffSettingsLiveData.observe(this, new Observer<StaffSettings>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable final StaffSettings newStaffSettings) {
                if(staffSettings.equals(newStaffSettings)) {
                  binding.txtSaveButton.setEnabled(false);
               } else {
                 binding.txtSaveButton.setEnabled(true);
               }
            }
        });
        binding.setSettings(staffSettingsLiveData.getValue());
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
        binding.executePendingBindings();
```

I am new to the LiveData. I am not able to figure out the issue.